# Build a JSON object using for loop with python

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I am new to python and trying to write a simple script that pushes notification to my slack channel about open tickets in my queue.

I am trying to submit the below JSON object to a slack webhook but not sure how to achieve the end result that looks like below.

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "There are *2* open tickets :in the queue\n *Ticket Details *"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*12345* - High CPU usage on prod app1 server"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*54321* - DB parameter modification - ProdDB03"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am doing an API call to an URL that gives me the open ticket details in a JSON format. I am able to parse through it and store the **Count** (number of open tickets), **Ticket ID** and the **Ticket Description** in respective variables.

I would like to create a block for each ticket as below.

```
{
  "type": "section",
  "text": {
    "type": "mrkdwn",
    "text": "*54321* - DB parameter modification - ProdDB03"
    }
}
```

Just ideas on how to achieve this without actual code would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: make a dictionary, do `json.dumps` on it.

Comment: @matszwecja Inside a for loop for each ticket I should use json.dumps(data) ?
What about the first and last blocks then ?

Comment: Make a dictionary corresponding to your entire JSON object, and call `json.dumps` once at the very end once the object is complete.

Comment: @matszwecja I was able to get this working by creating an empty Dictionary and appending data to it. I then added `json.dumps(data, indent = 2)` to the final dictionary and it worked. Thanks.